# Possible to hide tables depending on deployment configuration?

Tags: hibernate, orm, schema, db2

We will support several clients, and some DB tables should not be visible to all clients. We would however like to have identical schema for all clients due to ease of deployment.

1) Is it possible to "hide" some tables so that we could have identical schema for clients, but some tables are visible only in some deployments? We use Hibernate, and I'm unsure how this would affect mapping.

2) Another option would be to create views and map those to Hibernate in some cases when the physical table structure should not be revealed. Would this work with a DB2 database?

Any thoughts? Thanks for your input! :)

Comment: you could use SchemaExport to create the database and only include the mappings you need when building the configuration object

Answer (score 0):

In the moment, when hibernate opens a new configuration (i. e. when you call `Configuration.configure()`), hibernate checks all mapping files which it founds in hibernate.cfg.xml. This check includes a verification if the table and the mapped columns exist. If they don't exist, you immediately get an exception.

What you can do:
You deliver the same mapping files to all clients, but each client gets it own hibernate.cfg.xml, where only the tables, which he has, are included in the `<mapping...>` tag. In this case you even can deliver different mapping files for the same table (useful if different client have different versions of this table) and only one of these mapping files is mentioned in the hibernate.cfg.xml.

Comment: Unfortunately, if the client has access to these mapping files, this isn't secure.